# Validation is not working properly in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have created a login page with validations. I'm using Routes for the page navigations. At first I have redirection from index page to login page.(i.e., index->login) Then my validations worked perfectly fine.
Recently I have added a new home page. So, I'm loading this page first( i.e.,
index -> home -> login). This page contains a link to login page. 
The problem now is my validation is not working properly. The error messages are shown on the page load itself.

Below is the code :

```
<div class='form-fields'>
      <input type='email' name='mail_name' ng-model='mail' ng-pattern="emailFormat" required />
      <span class="error" ng-show="login.mail_name.$error.pattern">Not valid email!</span>
</div>
<div class='form-fields'>
     <input class='input-fields' type='password' name='pwd_name' ng-model='password' ng-pattern='passwordFormat' required />
     <span class="error" ng-show="login.pwd_name.$error.pattern">Passowrd Error Message</span>
</div>
```

Js File :

```
$scope.mail = '';
$scope.emailFormat = /^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/;
$scope.password = '';
$scope.passwordFormat = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/;
```

Where I'm I going wrong?

Comment: are you wrapping it with a form? `<form name="login"> ... </form>`

Comment: yes. I'm using a form.

Comment: My js file is not getting triggered at all. And also I lost all the styles of login page.

Comment: Open your browser console. There probably is an error there that needs to be fixed.

Comment: No. I can't see any errors in browser console.

Comment: can you post a simple example in plunkr, otherwise this is hard to troubleshoot

Comment: @Allen Here, I made one for the code you provided, and it seems to work fine. https://plnkr.co/edit/S1kjMTp1SpDzqLXcQvaf?p=info. There isn't much else to do without you providing more info.

Comment: @CShark I did the same thing before I used routiing and it was  completely file. I used routing from home page to login page. Then the problem is created.

Comment: @Allen can you post a reproducible example similar to the one I did?